# How to save an Excel file automatically when received in OutLook and received by a specific email address?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation, outlook-2016

I receive an email daily in Outlook from a the same email address that contains an .XLSX file as an attachment. I am semi-familiar with VBA and have used it in Access and Excel, but I am not getting very far in Outlook. I know how to add a module and run macros in Outlook. I also know how to add script to an email rule that has been created. I just can't figure out the code variation to put behind it. If someone could please help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. Email from sender X is received in the Outlook Inbox.
2. I move the email that contains the Excel file into a sub-folder nested in the inbox. (I know how to create a message rule to accomplish this.)
3. Once the email is moved to the specified sub-folder the Excel file that is attached gets automatically saved to a specific file path on my hard drive replacing the file that was saved the day before with the same file name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a Macro in Outlook using VBA

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/writing-an-outlook-macro

https://www.emaildoctor.org/blog/auto-save-specific-email-attachments-with-outlook-vba/

Comment: The code found at the emaildoctor.org/blog is incomplete and is more of an add to sell an automation addin.